# Broadcast Smart Contract 'Hello World' error

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, nodeos, keosd

I am going through the eos tutorial but I got stuck at the contract broadcast.

When I compile the contract with `eosio-cpp -o hello.wasm hello.cpp --abigen` the console seems to get stuck and I have to use CTRL+C to gain back control and following that I get:

Warning, empty ricardian clause file

Warning, empty ricardian clause file

Warning, action  does not have a ricardian contract

.abi and .wasm files for the contract are still generated.

When I try to broadcast my contract with `cleos set contract hello CONTRACTS_DIR/hello -p hello@active` I get the following:

Reading WASM from /home/techbro965/contracts/hello/hello.wasm...

Publishing contract...

Error 3070003: Serialization Error Processing WASM

Error Details: mutable globals cannot be imported: globalImport.type.isMutable

pending console output:

I am using eosio.cdt-1.4.1 and eosio_1.5.0_1_ubuntu-18.04
Below is my smart contract from the tutorial:

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>

using namespace eosio;

class [[eosio::contract("hello")]] hello : public contract {
  public:
  using contract::contract;

  [[eosio::action]]
  void hi( name user ) {
     print( "Hello, ", user);
  }
};

EOSIO_DISPATCH( hello, (hi))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved, it was a problem with the virtual machine setup. For EOS to work properly it requires a minimum of 2 CPU cores.